Excel O365 - manually created customUI ribbon not appearing
I have created an extensive macro project which I would like to make available to my colleagues. For better usability, I would like to do this as an add-in with its own ribbon. When creating the customUI file, I used this answer as a guide, as I also use a work computer and only have limited rights. I also compared to this answer, which is basically the same but a bit newer.
Unfortunately, the ribbon I created is not displayed and I don't get an error. I have added the customizations to my file both saved as .xlsm as well as .xlam, both without success. I have tried to debug using these instructions, but get no error or even a hint.
Here is my customUI/customUI.xml file:
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
   <ribbon  startFromScratch="false"> 
     <tabs> 
       <tab id="CustomTab" label="smartVC"> 
         <group id="StkAnal" label="Strukturanalyse"> 
           <button id="Btn1" label="Analyse" screentip="FPS-OPS abgleichen" supertip="Strukturen analysieren und abgleichen" size="large" imageMso="SmartArtOrganizationChartRightHanging" onAction="abgleich" />
     </group>
     <group id="Nav" label="Navigation">
       <button id="Btn2" label="prev loc" screentip="Vorheriges loc KMAT" supertip="Zum vorherigen loc KMAT springen" size="medium" imageMso="ShapeUpArrow" onAction="prev_loc" /> 
           <button id="Btn3" label="next loc" screentip="Nächstes loc KMAT" supertip="Zum nächsten loc KMAT springen" size="medium" imageMso="ShapeDownArrow" onAction="next_loc" />
       <button id="Btn4" label="in FPS" screentip="Zeige KMAT in FPS" supertip="Zum entsprechenden FPS KMAT springen" size="medium" imageMso="LeftArrow2" onAction="find_in_FPS" /> 
           <button id="Btn5" label="in OPS" screentip="Zeige KMAT in OPS" supertip="Zum entsprechenden OPS KMAT springen" size="medium" imageMso="RightArrow2" onAction="find_in_OPS" />
     </group>
         <group id="Format" label="Formatierung"> 
           <button id="Btn6" label="EA" screentip="Markiert als EA" supertip="Zelle orangenen Rahmen hinzufügen" size="medium" imageMso="QueryAppend" onAction="mark_ea" />
           <button id="Btn7" label="ST" screentip="EA Markierung entfernen" supertip="Zellenrahmen entfernen" size="medium" imageMso="QueryDelete" onAction="unmark_ea" />
           <button id="Btn8" label="func" screentip="färben als func KMAT" supertip="Zellenfarbe Hellblau setzen" size="medium" imageMso="AppointmentColor2" onAction="mark_func" />
           <button id="Btn9" label="loc" screentip="färben als loc KMAT" supertip="Zellenfarbe Dunkelgrau setzen" size="medium" imageMso="JotInkStyle1" onAction="mark_loc" />
           <button id="Btn10" label="neu" screentip="markieren als neues KMAT" supertip="Zellenfarbe Gelb setzen" size="medium" imageMso="AppointmentColor10" onAction="mark_new" />
           <button id="Btn11" label="del" screentip="KMAT zum löschen markieren" supertip="Zellenfarbe Rot setzen" size="medium" imageMso="InkStopInkingReadingView" onAction="mark_del" />
           <button id="Btn12" label="todo" screentip="KMAT zum bearbeiten markieren" supertip="Zellenfarbe Hellgrau setzen" size="medium" imageMso="AppointmentColor4" onAction="mark_todo" />
     </group>
       </tab> 
     </tabs> 
   </ribbon> 
 </customUI>

... and the corresponding .rels file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
    <Relationship Id="rId3" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/extended-properties" Target="docProps/app.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId2" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships/metadata/core-properties" Target="docProps/core.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="xl/workbook.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId4" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/custom-properties" Target="docProps/custom.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="smartVCribbon" Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/relationships/ui/extensibility" Target="/customUI/customUI14.xml" />
</Relationships>

I am using Excel O365 and have installed a custom add-in which I do not have access to the code. However, I can create custom ribbons directly in Excel.
My questions are:

did I miss a mistake in the customization files?
Can the other macro prevent my ribbon from being displayed?
What else can I do to track down the error?


@AxelRichter is this the same as the Show add-in user interface errors checkbox? If so I already enabled it with no effect (see second paragraph). If it is another setting I was not able to find it in the options.

Do you want a   custom ribbon staying there All the time or only when the respective add-in is open? And disappearing if the add-in is closed... If so, I think a better/safer idea is to write the XML inside the add-in, using OfficeRibbonEditor. It will have an onLoad event able to set your IRibbon object, even to save its pointer in a way to be recuperated in case of VBA errors.

@FaneDuru The ribbon should be linked to the add-in. So if the add-in is installed/activated the ribbon should be there, if not it should disappear. I am not able to install third party software as I have limited rights on my work device, so I don't think the proposed editor is a solution for me...

@FaneDuru OK, you cannot install anything, but can you download a zip file? Is not needed to install OfficeRibbonEditor. Just downloading a folder containing some dlls, libs etc. (in a zip file) and run a file. It can be downloaded from GitHub. If I cannot find the link, I have it and I can put it here using a transfer site...

@FaneDuru thanks for the tip that the tool does not require instalation. This way I was able to run it and found the issue in the xml

I loaded your RibbonX into the "Office RibbonX Editor" and it immediately highlighted the issue: the size attribute can be either large or normal per 2.3.10 ST_Size (Control Size) and you are using medium. As such, the RibbonX load process is failing. Where you use medium, try changing all to normal (or large).

I just tried out the editor thanks to @FaneDuru who told me it doesn't need instalation and found out the same! Also it seems that the JotInkStyle1 is no longer there...
